# ¿Cómo mostrar las celdas con salto de linea usando Jquery DataTables al exportar a PDF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Aquí esta el ejemplo sin la funcionalidad esperada (que se muestren los saltos de lineas de mis celdas al exportar a PDF):

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtpi',
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'pdfHtml5',
      text: 'Save current page'
     }],
    columns: [
        {
            title: 'Person name',
            defaultContent: '', // if no content set in field
            data: 'name'
        },
        {
            title: 'Person age',
            type: 'num', // this would be a number field
            data: 'age'
        }
    ],
    data: [
        {name: 'John <br/> Doe', age: 25},
        {name: 'Michael <br/> Jackson', age: 30},
        {name: 'Tom Jones', age: 32},
        {name: 'Monica Beluchi', age: 34}
    ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.1/js/buttons.colvis.min.js"></script>




<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="r"> </div>
```

La tabla como se debería de ver al exportar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve al exportar al PDF:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta pregunta la hizo alguien y fue borrada anteriormente, la agregue para poner la respuesta y que sea de utilidad para la comunidad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta es la posible solución que encontré.

El detalle es extender la funcionalidad del botón exportar para que reemplace `<br/>` por `\n`, espero que te sea de utilidad, saludos.

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtpi',
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'pdfHtml5',
      text: 'Save current page',
      exportOptions: {
        format: {
          body: function(data){
            //Antes de mandarse al PDF cada valor pasa por aqui y es evaluado
            var valor = data.toString(); //El campo debe ser STRING para que funcione
            valor = valor.replace("<br/>","\n");  //Aqui es donde le digo al JavaScript que reemplace <br/> el salto de linea HTML por el salto de linea \n
            return valor;
            }
          }
        }
      }
   ],
    columns: [
        {
            title: 'Person name',
            defaultContent: '', // if no content set in field
            data: 'name'
        },
        {
            title: 'Person age',
            type: 'num', // this would be a number field
            data: 'age'
        }
    ],
    data: [
        {name: 'John <br/> Doe', age: 25},
        {name: 'Michael <br/> Jackson', age: 30},
        {name: 'Tom Jones', age: 32},
        {name: 'Monica Beluchi', age: 34}
    ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.1/js/buttons.colvis.min.js"></script>




<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="r"> </div>
```

Ejemplo después de exportar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas , sabes como podría hacer un salto de linea la momento de exportar a excel , tengo problema al exportar el pide pagina , no se si podrias ayudarme. este es mi ejemplo :https://jsfiddle.net/Eufragio/u342qgoz/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6x5rzsdn/1/  Parece que esto funciona, pero tienes que darle doble click a la celda para visualizarlo, nose si es por mi version de excel... La mejor solución seria poner varios renglones(rows de excel) para el footer.

Comment: Buenas cristina , ya encontré mi solución, la compartire para que le sirva a otra persona : https://jsfiddle.net/m26nx9yg/   , Feliz dia gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! :D Genial

Comment: Que ingenioso lo pusiste como formula (Y) excelente